# Text flows past div

Tags: css, html

So I have a centered div that contains the content of my static site. I have the div anchored to the bottom of the page using this CSS

```
div#center_content {

position: absolute;
top:15px;
bottom: 0px;

left: 0;
right: 0;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;

width: 1000px;
background: #EEEEEE;
border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
/*
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 70%, #DADADA 99%);
*/
text-align: center;
}
```

The HTML is as follows:

```
    <div id="center_content">
        <h1 id="page-heading">Heading</h1>
        <hr id="first-rule"></hr>
        <div id="nav-list">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="index.html">about</a> </li>
            <li><a href="work.html">work</a></li> 
        </ul>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras aliquam auctor quam sed ultrices. Quisque hendrerit pellentesque leo eu condimentum. Morbi lorem enim, condimentum sed sem ut, auctor tempor ante. Praesent pulvinar elementum lorem, sit amet lobortis sem facilisis nec. Donec ultricies eros at placerat vulputate. Vestibulum a hendrerit erat. Vivamus varius cursus ipsum, sit amet cursus arcu volutpat vel. Duis congue dui a ornare ornare. Duis aliquam dui arcu, non tincidunt tortor euismod id. Cras auctor velit vitae odio malesuada convallis. Mauris odio dolor, hendrerit dapibus fringilla eget, aliquet in lorem. Nunc faucibus tristique eleifend. Vestibulum tellus ligula, volutpat commodo sollicitudin nec, suscipit quis urna. Nunc varius fringilla commodo.

        Aenean nec nunc varius, consequat velit id, sodales lorem. Etiam luctus sapien id odio suscipit tincidunt. Donec nec dolor eget lacus ornare iaculis. In quis iaculis urna, eu pharetra odio. Nullam sit amet purus sit amet eros blandit viverra vel quis sapien. Suspendisse potenti. Donec vel aliquam quam. Curabitur tempor fermentum lectus at laoreet. Nullam vehicula metus ut lectus congue, eu euismod urna placerat. Vestibulum ante ipsum primis in faucibus orci luctus et ultrices posuere cubilia Curae; In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam venenatis magna vitae risus ullamcorper, in egestas sem dapibus. Praesent tincidunt, ligula a eleifend facilisis, erat lectus molestie lorem, non volutpat arcu metus vel nunc. Nunc semper massa turpis. Ut et metus orci. Duis eu bibendum lorem.

        Phasellus id interdum metus. Suspendisse potenti. Cras vitae venenatis eros. Nam ac consequat dolor. Sed sed erat aliquam, lobortis est eu, adipiscing lorem. Aliquam imperdiet lacus id tristique tempor. Duis aliquet aliquam est quis ornare. Sed non pharetra velit. Etiam non enim tristique, luctus arcu rutrum, vulputate sem. Nullam posuere auctor ante vel vulputate. Nulla nec felis ut purus condimentum adipiscing sed sit amet urna. Vivamus vel fringilla odio. Morbi suscipit vel risus non suscipit. Nullam eget lectus ultrices odio euismod dictum. Curabitur libero nibh, interdum quis sem sed, sagittis gravida velit.

        Maecenas ultrices erat sit amet elit egestas blandit. Ut vitae hendrerit purus. Nullam hendrerit est commodo leo tempus rhoncus. Proin mauris libero, auctor vitae augue a, fringilla accumsan velit. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ut lacus tellus. Suspendisse sed suscipit magna. Nulla fermentum, tortor vel mattis condimentum, dui eros interdum tortor, non dignissim neque urna id erat. Ut et ante ut eros consequat dapibus a interdum risus.
        </p>

    </div>
```

The problem is that when there is a lot of text (as in this example) the text overflows the div with the grey div and when the user scrolls down, the text spills off of the grey div and onto the background. In other words, the div is not fitting the content. The div will resize when I resize the window, but not when I scroll. Scrolling is what seems to break everything.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gm8T4/1/ (I changed the width to 500px to make it easier to see the problem.)

EDIT 2: I'd really like to avoid using the `overflow` property as I don't want to get rid of the browser scrollbars and I don't want to give the div scrollbars.

Comment: please create a fiddle

Comment: Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gm8T4/1/

Comment: Just a note: I'm not sure you need those `hr`s. You should be able to just use `border-bottom` in this case.

Comment: Thanks! I'll check into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
div#center_content {
    position: relative;
    top: 15px;
    min-height: calc(100% - 15px);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    /*
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFFFFF 70%, #DADADA 99%);
*/
    text-align: center;
}
```

I have changed position and min-height.

EDIT: calc() has support problems in some current mobile browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc And calc() is not working with viewport units in chrome.

Comment: Thanks I like this solution because it does not replace the browser scroll bars with the div scroll bars. The div is now properly containing the text, but one thing: when there is a small amount of text in the div, the div does not go all the way to the bottom of the page (it just fits the content and leaves a huge margin at the bottom). Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: It's chrome bug, viewport units are not working with calc. Sorry about that. I would use JavaScript to set min-height of #center_content to window.innerHeight - 15px. Or you can create next div, below this one, set height to something around 90%, position: fixed, bottom: 0, jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/factoradic/5D6Zz/1/

Comment: Ah, I forget, with #under you don't need min-height.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to scroll the text in the div and not the whole page, this is what your div needs:

```
overflow-y:scroll;
```

This removes the scrollbar from the page but adds a vertical scrollbar to your div. Use

```
overflow: scroll;
```

to allow scrolling also horizontally. Both solutions work in all major browsers.

Answer (score 0):

To stay with the scrollbar at the page border, you can also add a div as a body child:

```
<div id="topbar"></div>
```

using

```
div#topbar { position: fixed; z-index:1; top:0; width:100%; height: 15px; background-color:white;}
```

and setting `position:relative;` and `top:0` to your `div#center_content`.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
overflow: auto;
```

to `div#center_content` style.

```
div#center_content {
    overflow:auto;  
    position: absolute;
    top:15px;
    bottom: 0px;

    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

    width: 500px;
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;

    font-size: 24px;

    text-align: center;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gm8T4/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses Ryan Fait's [sticky footer](http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/) to extend your content div to the bottom of the page (with the sticky footer hidden).

#### HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div id="center_content">
        <h1 id="page-heading">Heading</h1>
        <hr id="first-rule"></hr>
        <div id="nav-list">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">work</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr></hr>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="push"></div>
</div>
<div class="footer">Boo</div>
```

#### CSS

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -4em;

    /* Custom styling */
    background: #EEEEEE;
    border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
    width: 500px;
}

/* Hidden sticky footer */
.footer, .push {
    height: 4em;
    display: none;
}

div#center_content {
    margin-top:15px;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/gm8T4/3/